# Multiple Report Columns in Reporting Services 2008

Tags: ssrs-2008

I'm using SSRS 2008 to make something for label printing.  I want to make use of all horizontal and vertical space on the page to fit as many labels as possible, so I'm thinking I probably want multiple Report Columns.

[This technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677374.aspx) would have you believe that you can set the number of Report Columns to make what they call "newsletter-style columns" in the Report Properties window.  If I bring up the Report Designer in my Visual Studio 2008 installation and click on Report -> Report Properties from the top menu, I see this:

[image: Hosted by imgur.com]

I can't find anything relating to columns, and no combination of the other settings on this page will make it change to multiple columns (yes, I'm rendering to PDF, not just checking the HTML preview.)  Any ideas?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out - when they say Report Properties, they don't mean the Report Properties dialogue that you might think.  click on a blank region of the report to select the Report object, then pop up the Properties pane and you'll see a "Columns" property which you can adjust.  Whew!

Comment: This deserves to be dug up and upvoted a million times. You have no idea how common this problem is and what lack of information (articulate information at that) there is on the internet. Bookmarked, noted, upvoted and saved.

But! Could you post your solution how you got your table/matrix to start showing data in the second column as it reaches the bottom of the page?

Comment: Hey David, this was a while back for me but I'll crack open my report (still working away!) when I get a chance and let you know more details.

Comment: Hi Barry,
That's alright; I was able to figure it out and get it working. :)